# Unable to add scroller inside a treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Im using customtkinter and trying to add CTKScrollbar inside CTkTable but getting this error

```
vertical_scrollbar = ctk.CTkScrollbar(third_frame_table, orientation="vertical", command=table.yview)
AttributeError: 'CTkTable' object has no attribute 'yview'
```

My Code:

```
table = CTkTable(third_frame_table, values=value, header_color="blue", corner_radius=0, command=table_opr)
table.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# Create a vertical scrollbar for the table
vertical_scrollbar = ctk.CTkScrollbar(third_frame_table, orientation="vertical", command=table.yview)
vertical_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

# Configure the table to use the scrollbar
table.configure(yscrollcommand=vertical_scrollbar.set)
```

Comment: some widgets may not work with `Scroller` and you may have to put this widget on `Canvas` and scroll canvas - and this will looks like scrolled widget.

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install CTkTable`